# Get Products metafields with rest api in shopify react-app

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to access shopify product metafields same like products getting with rest-api and also i am using shopify-api npm package to get metafields but we are receing empty metafields array

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRXjt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBXcA.png)
Please help me to resolve that..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of potential reasons. One, perhaps that product actually has no metafields. Or two, perhaps your API has no permission to read the metafields assigned to the product.

A sure fire way for you to establish if your code is working or not, is to use your API key to write a metafield. Verify it exists. Then use your code to read the metafield you created. With that, you know your code is working.